# Javascript: Getting cookie value to record user's visit

Tags: javascript

This script keeps track of the number of times a surfer has visited page, and show the surfer of this info. Also with buttons to allow him/her to reset info. When the "Revisit Page" button is clicked, it refresh the page. Get the message according to the number of visits and print it. When the "Reset Counter" is clicked, it set the counter to zero and refresh the page. I did coding almost but it's not working. Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code ?

code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>cookie</title>
        <style>

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="myDiv" id="div">
        <p id="txt">   </p> </div>
    <FORM>
        <CENTER>
            <INPUT NAME="update" TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Revisit  Page" OnClick="history.go(0)" id="revisit">
            <INPUT NAME="reset" TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Reset Counter" OnClick="ResetCounts()" id="reset">
        </CENTER>
    </FORM>

    <script>

        function getCookieVal (offset) {
            var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf (";", offset);
            if (endstr == -1)
                endstr = document.cookie.length;
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
        }
        function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
        function DisplayInfo() {
            var expdate = new Date();
            var visit;
            expdate.setTime(expdate.getTime() +  (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 365)); 
            if(!(visit = GetCookie("visit"))) 
                visit = 0;
            visit++;
            SetCookie("visit", visit, expdate, "/", null, false);
            var message;
            if(visit == 1) 
                message="         Welcome to my page!";
            if(visit== 2) 
                message="           I see you came back !";
            if(visit == 3) 
                message="               Oh, it's you again!";
            if(visit == 4)
                message="            You must be curious!"; 
            if(visit == 5) 
                message="      You're practically a regular!";
            if(visit == 6) 
                message="              You need a hobby!";
            if(visit == 7)
                message="             Nothing better to do?"; 
            if(visit == 8) 
                message="            Don't you ever sleep?";
            if(visit == 9)
                message="                      Get a life!!!"; 
            if(visit >= 10) 
                message="  Rent is due on the 1st of the month!";

            var txt = document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML =  "Your browser has visited this page " + visit + " time(s)." + message;    
        }
        function ResetCounts() {
            var expdate = new Date();
            expdate.setTime(expdate.getTime() +  (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 365)); 
            visit = 0;
            SetCookie("visit", visit, expdate , "/", null, false);
            history.go(0);
        }

        window.onload=DisplayInfo
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your line `if(!(visit = GetCookie("visit"))) visit = 0;` should have a double equals sign in the conditional.

Comment: Why does your title mention "next birthday"?

Comment: @ Obsidian Age  it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these two functions instead - they work on my eCommerce site.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Also make sure your own browser accepts cookies and isn't purging them while you're running tests.